# UDF not returning the same value as select contained in UDF

Tags: sql, t-sql

I created this UDF

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HasExtendedRetentionSamples] (@BoxNumber varchar(20))
RETURNS  int

AS  

BEGIN 

      declare @cnt int
      set @cnt  = 0

      select @cnt =     (select count(*)
            from tFreezerBoxInfo bi
            inner join tFreezerDetails fd on fd.boxTrayId = bi.boxTrayId
            inner join tncDrugTestListNew dt on dt.labnumber = fd.labnumber
            inner join ExtendedRetentionSites a on dt.number = a.number
            where boxnumber = 'ND011811001'
            and 
            case isnull([retention],0)
                when 0 then proposedDestructionDate
                else dateadd(dd,abs([retention]),proposedDestructionDate)
            end  <> proposedDestructionDate)

      return @cnt

END
```

When I execute the UDF

```
select dbo.[HasExtendedRetentionSamples] ('ND011811001')
```

The value 0 is returned, which is incorrect,

When I execute the SQL statement contained in the UDF (replacing @BoxNumber with 'ND011811001')...

```
select count(*)
  from tFreezerBoxInfo bi
  inner join tFreezerDetails fd on fd.boxTrayId = bi.boxTrayId
  inner join tncDrugTestListNew dt on dt.labnumber = fd.labnumber
  inner join ExtendedRetentionSites a on dt.number = a.number
  where boxnumber = 'ND011811001'
  and 
  case isnull([retention],0)
        when 0 then proposedDestructionDate
        else dateadd(dd,abs([retention]),proposedDestructionDate)
  end  <> proposedDestructionDate
```

The value 5 is returned, which is correct.

So the big question is WHY????

All the datatype in the joins & case statement are the same.

Comment: I noticed that your UDF is using a hardcoded value for BoxNumber instead of the parameter you are passing in.  This may not make a difference, but it's certainly something you'll want to change before declaring the function "Done".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am embarrassed to say, I have found out why this was happening.....

When I created the table ExtendedRetentionSites, it was created & populated with me as the owner.  I realized that and recreated the table with DBO as the owner, populating this table, but never dropping the table with the same name that I owned. I ran an insert statement & it inserted into ExtendedRetentionSites that I owned, but this data never made it to the table that DBO owned.

Soooooo when I ran the select script, it used ExtendedRetentionSites that I owned, that had the new row, that would give me the results I was looking for.  When I ran the UDF, it used the table that DBO owned, without the new row thus returning nothing or a zero count.

Thanks to everyone who helped me out with this, I will now pull my head out of my ass & get back to work.

Thanks again to all!!!!

Comment: Glad you finally figured it out. You had me stumped on why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the function to this, take the count out of the subquery:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[HasExtendedRetentionSamples] (@BoxNumber varchar(20))
RETURNS  int

AS  

BEGIN 

      declare @cnt int
      set @cnt  = 0

      select @cnt = count(*)
            from tFreezerBoxInfo bi
            inner join tFreezerDetails fd on fd.boxTrayId = bi.boxTrayId
            inner join tncDrugTestListNew dt on dt.labnumber = fd.labnumber
            inner join ExtendedRetentionSites a on dt.number = a.number
            where boxnumber = 'ND011811001'
            and 
            case isnull([retention],0)
                when 0 then proposedDestructionDate
                else dateadd(dd,abs([retention]),proposedDestructionDate)
            end  <> proposedDestructionDate

      return @cnt

END
```

try changing your `CASE` statement to:

```
case 
    when isnull([retention],0) = 0 then proposedDestructionDate
    else dateadd(dd,abs([retention]),proposedDestructionDate)
end  <> proposedDestructionDate
```

Comment: if you run the code from the declare through the select and then use print @cnt, what do you get?

Comment: are you sure you are passing in the correct value when you call the UDF?

Comment: Positive, cut & paste.  Just found something bizarre, when I comment out the join of ExtendedRetentionSites & everything after the 'and' in the where statement, the UDF returns something other than 0.  When I uncomment the join commented out above, the result goes back to 0.

Comment: if you put your case statement in parentheses what happens?

Comment: I just edited my answer with a change to your CASE statement.

Comment: That did not work either... one thing to note tncDrugRestListNew is a view.

Comment: I would advise added the correct table aliases to the columns in your WHERE clause.